# RegExp for BBCode tags javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

I have this RegExp, and i dont know what's wrong with it

```
tag = new RegExp('(\\['+tag+'=("|'|)(.*?)\1\\])((?:.|\\r?\\n)*?)\\[/'+tag+']','g');
```

The bbcode tags can have double quotation marks, single quotation marks or no quotation marks.

```
[tag="teste"]123[/tag]
[tag='teste']123[/tag]
[tag=teste]123[/tag]
```

Desired output in captures: `teste` and `123`

To match the optional quotation marks, it should be `("|'|)`, `(["|\']*)` or `("|\'?)`?

Comment: Just some syntax errors: `new RegExp('(\\['+tag+'=(["\']|)(.*?)\\1\\])([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']','g');`. I also change `((?:.|\\r?\\n)*?)` to `([\s\S]*?)`, since it seems to be your intention

Comment: if you don't know what's wrong with it, then how do you know it's wrong?

Comment: @Eduardo I found it difficult to read, so I expanded based on the info you provided in comments / answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Whats wrong with the string

First, let's correct the syntax in your string

- You need to define the var `tag`

  ```
  tag = 'tag';
  result = new RegExp( <...>  );
  ```
- You have unballanced quotes in `'("|'|) <...> '`, that needs to be escaped as `("|\'|)`
- Also, escape `\1` as `\\1`

so now we have the expression `'(\\['+tag+'=("|\'|)(.*?)\\1\\])((?:.|\\r?\\n)*?)\\[/'+tag+']'` with the value:

```
(\[tag=("|'|)(.*?)\1\])((?:.|\r?\n)*?)\[/tag]
```

### What's wrong with the RegEx

Only one thing really, in `("|\'|)(.*?)\\1` you're using `\1` to match the same quotation mark as the one used as opening. However, the 1 refers to the first capturing group (the first parenthesis from left to right), but `("|'|)` is actually the second set of parenthesis, the second group. All you need to do is change it to `\2`.

```
(\[tag=("|'|)(.*?)\2\])((?:.|\r?\n)*?)\[/tag]
```

That's it!

### Let's add some final suggestions

- Instead of `.*?` I would use `[^\]]+` (any characters except "]")
- Use the **i** modifier (case-insensitive match, for "[tag]...[/TaG]")
- `("|'|)` is the same as `("|'?)`
- Instead of `(?:.|\r?\n)*?` I would use `[\s\S]*?` as @nhahtdh suggested

### Code:

```
tag = 'tag';
result = new RegExp('(\\['+tag+'=("|\'?)([^\\]]+)\\2\\])([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']','gi');
```

**Alternative:** [EDIT: from info added in comments]

```
result = new RegExp('\\['+tag+'(?:=("|\'?)([^\\]]+)\\1)?\\]([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']', 'gi');
```

As for your second question: Although both `(["|\']*)` and `("|\'?)` will match, the latter is the correct way for what you're trying to match. The `*` looks for 0 to infinite repetitions, and the `|` is interpreted as literal in a character class. Instead, `("|\'?)` matches a single quote, a double quote, or none.

Comment: What was the way i wanted was the following code:

new RegExp('\\['+tag+'(?:=["\']([^\\]]+)["\'])?\\]([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']', 'gi');

Comment: That code needs to be properly escaped. I assume you're now specifying: (**a**) you don't need the first group, and (**b**) the `='hello'` part in the tag is optional but it should always have quotation marks. Code: `result = new RegExp('\\['+tag+'(?:=(["\'])([^\\]]+)\\1)?\\]([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']','gi');` [Live example](https://regex101.com/r/aY7eL0/1)

Comment: The best for me was the following:
var re = new RegExp('\\['+tag+'(?:=(["\']*)([^\\]]+)\\1)?\\]([\\s\\S]*?)\\[/'+tag+']', 'gi');

Comment: I don't understand why you are repeating the quotes in `["\']*`. Check the escapes on that expression. When using the RegExp constructor, every backslash should be put as `\\\`